# Microsoft Edge request insecure content in secure page

Tags: iframe, microsoft-edge

When Microsoft Edge opens a page which contains an iframe in secure mode, it will also request the target page even if the schema of the iframe is HTTP.

This may cause user send some non-encrypted content even in secure mode. As I tested, this content even may contain cookies which leads to great risk.

I have created a project testing this issue at https://github.com/Anduin2017/EdgeProblem.

But I wondered if it was a problem Microsoft Edge itself or my mistake?

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft has fixed this issue.